# Jqgrid animate opening/closing of subgrid like jquerUi Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using the jqGrid-subGrid option in my grid. Every row has a subgrid and I'm trying to animate the opening and closing of the subgrid, like the jqueryui accordion does.

There are the two functions

- collapseSubGridRow
- expandSubGridRow

but I can't find the right trigger for the click event to change the opening.
Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not include animation it just closes previously opened sub-grid so there's only one grid opened at a time - like with accordion.

```
 var expandedRowId=null;

 $("#jqgrid_0").jqGrid({
    ...,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
       if(expandedRowId!=null && expandedRowId!=row_id){
           $("#jqgrid_0").jqGrid ('toggleSubGridRow', expandedRowId);
       }
       expandedRowId=row_id
       ...
    },
    // clicking on row will toggle sub-grid
    onSelectRow: function (rowId) {
        if(expandedRowId==rowId)expandedRowId=null;
        $("#jqgrid_0").jqGrid ('toggleSubGridRow', rowId);
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps.